# XML loop not putting contents inside node

Tags: java, xml, if-statement

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
<CTS>
   <startTime>00:00:00</startTime>
   <endTime>00:00:00</endTime>
</CTS>
```

As you can see the start time and end time sit inside the CTS,

This is my code

```
 if (headerString.equals("startTime") || headerString.equals("endTime")){        

      Element headerElement1 = document.createElement("CTS");  

      Element st = document.createElement("startTime");//create a new element
      Element et = document.createElement("endTime");//create a new element

      if (headerString.equals("startTime")) {         

          Text st1 = document.createTextNode(s);//contents of the node
          st.appendChild(st1);//apend the text contents 
          headerElement1.appendChild(st);
          productElement.appendChild(headerElement1);

          index++;         
      }   

      if (headerString.equals("endTime")) {  

         Text et1 = document.createTextNode(s);//contents of the node
         et.appendChild(et1);//apend the text contents
         headerElement1.appendChild(et);
         productElement.appendChild(headerElement1);

         index++;
      }
```

however what i am getting is:

```
<CTS>
    <startTime>01:00:00</startTime>
</CTS>
<CTS>
    <endTime>05:00:00</endTime>
</CTS>
```

I am therefore creating the element CTS twice one for startTime and one for the endTime, how do i change my code so that i get what i am trying to achive?

Comment: If you would post you complete code WITH the loop, it you be easier to explain... Assuming you only have posted the code inside the loop you did "productElement.appendChild(headerElement1) once and only once. You need to move your
    Element headerElement1 = document.createElement("CTS");
outside the loop.

Comment: @Viacheslav Vedenin just moved the Element headerElement1 = document.createElement("CTS"); before the loop began and that solved it - many thanks